# Sharepoint 2010 Claim base authentication error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created a sitecollection using domain user as primary admin and fba user as secondary admin but whenever i try to login using the fba user i get the following error,

An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs..

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you have missed FBA configuration in web config of your web application

take help from following post although it is for ADFS FBA

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2010/01/07/setting-up-fba-claims-in-sharepoint-2010-with-active-directory-membership-provider.aspx